# Update or add Url parameter without removing existing url parameters

Tags: jquery

Update or add Url parameter without removing existing url parameters

Url
http://www.example.com?qid=123

After adding parameter
http://www.example.com?product_id=353

I have code but it is removing the existing URL parameter "quid"

```
var stateObj = { product_id: "353" };
window.history.pushState({}, "Products", '?'+jQuery.param(stateObj));
```

i want url like, How to achieve this?
http://www.example.com?qid=123&product_id=353

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember all other values and then push them all..

```
var stateObj = { product_id: "353", gid: '1222' };
window.history.pushState({}, "Products", '?'+jQuery.param(stateObj));
```